# DAX Measure Calculation Two Different Tables

Tags: powerbi, sum, dax

I have one question about DAX calculation?

Hi Guys,

I have one question about DAX Measure Calculation

Please Help me get the solution of this problem

I have 2 tables

table 1 - Purchase Info

(Column name - Customer ID, Product ID, Quantity, Payment Mode)

table 2 - Product Info

(Column name - Product ID, Product Name, Product Cost, Selling Cost, Tax Amount)

My Question Is, How to Calculate Total Revenue?

The Table 1 (Purchase Info) have repeated customers and more than 10 thousand of records and also records are shuffled. The table 2 (Product Info) have only 10 products and unique records ( Product ID). How to calculate the total revenue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This will work if you linked your tables via Product ID.

```
SUMX(
    Prod
    ,CALCULATE(SUMX(Sales,Sales[Quantity]))*Prod[Selling Cost]
)
```